# Dynamic white space in Drupal block side-bar

Tags: php, html, drupal, web, block

I am using Drupal 7 to build a website and I am using a side tab widget in a block (html).
It has three tabs with different contents.
In the first tab the content is bigger and there is more "body" white space but when I select the second tab the footer of the site comes up to fill the blank space. Can i have a stable footer and body ?
http://themeforest.net/item/coworker-responsive-retina-multipurpose-theme/full_screen_preview/4608484 . Here under pages->services. In the last tab , the footer changes its position depending on the size of the content in each tab.

Comment: Do you really expect someone to know what you are talking about? Some sort of image to show what you are talking about would probably be a good idea.

Comment: Sorry about that , http://themeforest.net/item/coworker-responsive-retina-multipurpose-theme/full_screen_preview/4608484 . Here under pages->services. In the last tab , the footer changes its position depending on the size of the content in each tab.

Comment: Setting the height on the div to be the same for each tab content should make it so the footer always stay in the same place. eg. `.tab_container .tab_content { height: 200px; }`

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your answer 2pha it works great. The only problem was that I had to use very big numbers in order to be responsive , because while making the browser window smaller the height stays the same and the text dissapears.